# windows explorer context menu in java

Tags: java, swing, winapi, swt, contextmenu

Consider simple application, that display list of file. I would like to display context menu , when user click of file or folder, the same as, when user right mouse click in windows explorer (open, rename, edit etc.). I don't want to create my own context menu, I want to show windows os context menu, using some kind of winapi probably. This should works only on windows machine.

Is it possible to achieve it with Swing or SWT or any other UI controls ?

Comment: The `java.awt.Desktop` class can provide the ability to open/edit with default app.  For rename/copy/delete, see the `java.io.File` class or the new file related APIs in Java 7.  Note that I guess this ability would be 2-3 lines of code in .Net.  You should consider using it, if only targeting Windows.

Comment: Raymond Chen wrote an [eleven part series](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=IContextMenu&sections=2905) explaining how to do this in C/C++.  It's really not straightforward.

Comment: To pile on to what @arx said, once you've gotten the C/C++ code going such that you're contributing to Windows Explorer, then if you want your business logic in Java, you'll have to fire up a Java runtime and then use some COM or something to get messages back and forth.  Fun times!

Comment: Similar question is asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247033/how-can-i-use-the-systems-context-menu-for-files-in-a-java-application)

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#unknown_93012) explains how it is done:

> Windows Explorer calls a folder object's `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf` to request an interface for one of the objects.... When a user right-clicks an object, Windows Explorer requests an `IContextMenu` interface.

There is a full source code example in C [here](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0006/Using_the_shell_context_menu.htm).